# What is _PTR_LD() in stdlib.h used for?

Tags: c++

I was looking through stdlib.h within the include files for Dev-Cpp and I found a certain line:

```
#define _PTR_LD(x) ((unsigned char  *)(&(x)->ld))
```

I then tried to use _PTR_LD in a program as follows:

```
class Thing {
public:
    Thing();
    int ld;
};

int main() {
    Thing x;
    x.ld = 8;
    cout << _PTR_LD(x) << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I thought it would return the value for the attribute ld within x, but I got the following error message:

15  10  C:\Users\John\Desktop\Untitled1.cpp [Error] base operand of '->' has non-pointer type 'Thing'

I tried to search for _PTR_LD() but I found nothing about it. Does anyone know anything about _PTR_LD()?

Comment: You need to pass a pointer, the order of operations is `&(x->ld)`. Also it evaluates to an `unsigned char *` so I'd assign `0x38` to `x.ld`.

Answer (score 0):

What it does literally is take an expression that evaluates to a pointer, `x`, and returns a pointer to `x->ld`, reinterpreted as an `unsigned char*`.

What you're doing doesn't compile because `->` has higher precedence than `&`, so your code evaluates to `&(x->ld)`, which is invalid. If you instead printed the following:

```
x.ld = 'a';
std::cout << ( _PTR_LD(&x)) << std::endl;
```

then you'd see `a` printed, since you're reinterpreting `&(x.ld)` as a C-string, and that memory happens to look like the string `{'a', 0}`.

As to *why* this macro exists, I don't know. Does it matter? It's a reserved, internal-use macro.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I assumed the & sign was used for x instead of x->ld.